# cannot borrow X as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust

In a simple game loop I have `active_player` pointing to one of 2 player objects.

```
let mut active_player = &mut self.player1;
loop {
     // do stuff with active_player

    println!("{} {}", self.player1.last_move(), self.player2.last_move());

    // Switch to next player
}
```

The problem comes when I try to read `self.player1.last_move()`  I understand why I'm getting the error but I don't know the proper pattern to solve this.  Is this an instance where `active_player` should be an `Rc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the mutable borrow extends the entire body of the `loop`. [Here is a simple reproduction of your issue](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5934cd696ed41b7c3262a05e025af7ac&version=stable&backtrace=0).

You can limit the scope of the mutable borrow, by moving it into the `loop`.. perhaps like this:

```
loop {
    {
        let mut active_player = &mut self.player1; // or perhaps self.get_active_player(); ?
        // ... do stuff with active_player ...
    }

    println!("{} {}", self.player1.last_move(), self.player2.last_move());

    // Switch to next player
}
```

[Here is a Gist that fixes it, as above](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5bcb1cf56e2f5c1513347310f07f27b1&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: Well, the idea is that first time through the loop `active_player` is self.player1, next time it's player2, then back to player1.  By changing the scope of `active_player` here I lose who was the active player, which is needed to switch to the next player

Comment: Yeah, your solution will work. I didn't try to write the "switch to next player" part until just now... that ran into problems with multiple borrows.  I'll just have to track the active player with an integer or something

Comment: I imagine you could perhaps move the "get active player" logic into a method of its own. Without knowing the internals of the rest of your game I can't really suggest how you would go about that though.

Comment: Oh wow I'm slow on typing today - I am glad you figured it out and my answer was helpful.

Comment: Thanks.  Rust day #2... fighting with the borrow checker

Comment: ...and it will continue for at least a few weeks, trust me :) Eventually it'll all click though and you'll fight it less and less. Its been a while since I've had to sit back and actually _think_ about whats wrong with the code I've written. It gets to the point where you consider the borrow checker errors to be glaringly obvious mistakes on your part and you'll feel comfortable fixing it up. It just takes a little bit of time thats all.